# How do I reset the "don't ask me again" checkbox in an IDA popup?

Tags: ida

I was just debugging something in IDA and it told me that the instruction pointer was pointing into the middle of an instruction, and asked if I would like to have it disassemble the middle of the instruction. In my particular case I never want to do that, so I checked "don't ask me again", but then I clicked yes accidentally, so now it's redefining my code and throwing away my carefully written comments every time I step. How do I reset this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Windows -> Reset hidden messages`.

[image]

[image]